Integral of complementary error function times exponential with polynomial argument
I try to understand the behavior of the following integral as $a\rightarrow\infty$
$$I(\delta)=\int_{-\delta}^\delta{\rm erfc}\Big(-\frac t{\sqrt a}\Big){\rm e}^{bt-t^2/a}{\rm d} t,$$
where ${\rm erfc(x)}$ is the complementary error function and $b$ can be written as a power of $a$. According to Mathematica, I already know that
$$J(\delta)=\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}{\rm e}^{bt-t^2/a}{\rm d} t=\frac12\sqrt{\pi a}{\rm e}^{ab^2/4}\Big\{{\rm erf}\Big(\frac{ab+2\delta}{2\sqrt a}\Big)-{\rm erf}\Big(\frac{ab-2\delta}{2\sqrt a}\Big)\Big\},$$
but Mathematica doesn't compute $I(\delta)$. It appears from the above estimation that, with $\delta=ab$, we have
$$J(\delta)=_{a\to\infty}\sqrt{\pi a}{\rm e}^{ab^2/4}\{1+O(a^{-m})\},\ m\in\mathbb{N}.$$ Do we have a similar approximation for $I(\delta)$? Is it possible to find a closed formula for $J(\delta)$ similar to the one for $I(\delta)$?

You have three parameters, $\delta, a, b$, could you please tell us explicitly what is the relationship between them in the situations you are interested in?

We can assume that $b=O(a^{-\alpha})$ with $0<\alpha<1/2$ and I need to find $\delta$ such that $I(\delta)=I(\infty){1+O(a^{-m})},\quad(m\in\mathbb{N})$.

$\newcommand\de\delta\newcommand\erfc{\operatorname{erfc}}$If $0<\de=o(\sqrt a)$, then $\erfc(-\frac t{\sqrt a})\to1$ and $e^{-t^2/a}\to1$ uniformly in $t\in[-\de,\de]$, whence
$$\begin{aligned}
I(\de)&\sim \int_{-\de}^{\de}e^{bt}\,dt  
=\frac2b\,\sinh(b\de)
\end{aligned}$$
if $b\ne0$, and $I(\de)\sim2\de$ if $b=0$.

Now consider the following limit conditions, which seem to be close to what the OP had in mind:
$$a\to\infty,\quad b\ge1,\quad(\de-ab/2)/\sqrt a\to\infty. $$
Then we can find a varying $C$ such that
$$C\to\infty,\quad C-b\sqrt a/4\to-\infty. $$
Write
$$I(\de)=I_1+I_2,$$
where
$$I_1:=\int_{-\de}^{C\sqrt a}\erfc(-t/\sqrt a)e^{bt-t^2/a}dt,\quad
I_2:=\int_{C\sqrt a}^\de\erfc(-t/\sqrt a)e^{bt-t^2/a}dt,$$
Next,
\begin{equation}
    I_1\le2\int_{-\de}^{C\sqrt a}e^{bt}dt=O(e^{Cb\sqrt a})=o(e^{ab^2/4}), 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    I_2\sim2\int_{C\sqrt a}^\de e^{bt-t^2/a}dt
    =2e^{ab^2/4}\sqrt a\,\int_{C-b\sqrt a/2}^{(\de-ab/2)/\sqrt a} e^{-z^2}dz
    \sim2e^{ab^2/4}\sqrt a\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2}dz
    =2\sqrt{\pi a}\, e^{ab^2/4}.
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
    I(\de)\sim2\sqrt{\pi a}\, e^{ab^2/4}.
\end{equation}

Thank you, it helped. Going further, one can derive an error term for $I(\delta)$. Indeed, with the condition $b=O(a^{-\alpha})$, $0<\alpha<1/2$ and the choices $C:=\log(a)$, $\delta:=a^{-\alpha+1}$, we can see, using
$$\rm{erfc}(x)=2+O\Big(\frac{{\rm e}^{-x^2/a}\sqrt{a}}{x\sqrt\pi}\Big),$$
that
$$I(\delta)=2\sqrt{\pi a}{\rm e}^{ab^2/4}{1+O(a^{-m}},\quad(m\in\mathbb{N}).$$

Can we imagine doing something similar with higher degree polynomial inside the exponential? Dealing with something like
$$\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}{\rm erfc}\Big(-\frac{t}{\sqrt a}\Big){\rm e}^{bt-t^2/a+t^3/a^2-t^4/a^3}$$
and so on?

@JeanDELI : I think this should be possible, under appropriate conditions on $\delta, a, b$. You may want to consider posting such a question separately, after some preparations, including stating the conditions on the parameters.

Alright, will do. Last question, what if $b\leq -1$ this time? I guess we can derive a similar result, cutting the integral at $-C\sqrt a$?

@losifPinelis When $b<0$, it seems that the final expression is quite different from the one in the case $b>0$. Using this I found that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm erfc}\Big(-\frac{t}{\sqrt a}\Big){\rm e}^{-bt-t^2/a} dt\sim\frac{2\sqrt 2}{|b|}{\rm e}^{ab^2/8}$$
I would like to prove this stands for $I(\delta)$ with a similar value for $\delta$ than the case $b>0$ but we can't use exactly the same method due to the change of sign of ${\rm erfc}$ after the substitution $u=-t$.

@JeanDELI : I think you should have specified how $\delta,a,b$ vary, as was pointed out by Aleksei Kulikov. In your example, $\delta=ab>0$ and $a\to\infty$ -- so, $b>0$. My answer considers a generalization of this setting. If you want to explore more, please do it in a separate post.
